# Проблема с картами Weather maps 1.0 на openweathermap

Tags: android, карты, openweathermap, weather

Хочу разобраться, как работает API для погодных карт openweathermap 1.0. С запросом я, вроде как, разобрался. JSON погоды парсится норм. а вот при прикручивании карты (загружаю получаемую ссылку в webview). Карта выглядит более-менее нормально только на минимальном зуме
[https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/clouds_new/0/0/0.png?appid={API}](https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/clouds_new/0/0/0.png?appid=%7BAPI%7D)
при дальнейшем увеличении (zoom>6)возникает ощущение, что сервер возвращает только одну плитку.
При этом похожие запросы на openstreets или https://sat.owm.io/sql с увеличением зума работают корректно.